# phpmyadmin mySQL create column with value "AS" not happening

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

need:
to enter integer IP value in ip_n and use internal INET_NTOA() function of mysql to fill in ip_a column. but using phpMyAdmin, i am not even able to create the table correctly.
I did this:

[image]

but it is wrong: for IP: 192.168.1.1

[image]

the second column is:

[image]

inspiration comes from here: http://databaseblog.myname.nl/2011/07/working-with-ips-in-mysql-and-mariadb.html

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html: _“The `DEFAULT` clause specifies a default value for a column. [With one exception,] the default value **must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression**.”_ (The exception being CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME colum.) So what you have specified as default value here is only the _text_ `INET_NTOA(ip_n)`, _literally_.

Comment: pl look at the link cited in the question, that gentleman is able to do it. how???

Comment: Have you considered a trigger?

Comment: The article talks about a feature in MariaDB, not MySQL.

Comment: @CBroe post that as the answer. Persistent virtual columns are MariaDB only.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to declare a default value for a column based on the contents of another column.

Unfortunately, You Can't Do That.®

Comment: oh ok. So how is this happening?:   mysql> CREATE TABLE `iptest`(`ip_n` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `ip_a` CHAR(15) AS (INET_NTOA(`ip_n`)) PERSISTENT, PRIMARY KEY(`ip_n`), KEY `ip_a` (`ip_a`));

Comment: +1. Only default values allowed for VARCHAR column are NULL or a string literal. The behavior described by OP is exactly what we expect.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the column is being given a DEFAULT value of a **string literal**.  Perfectly valid to assign a string literal, in this case, **`'INET_NTOA(ip_n)'`**. That may look like a reference to a MySQL function, but MySQL is seeing that as a **literal**.

If we ran an INSERT statement and allowed MySQL to assign the default value, we'd expect that exact literal to be stored in the column; and that's exactly what we'd expect to be returned in a SELECT.

(The behavior described as observed by OP.)

Note that MySQL only allows a *literal* value to be specified as the `DEFAULT` value for a VARCHAR column.  Actually, this is true for all datatypes, with the exception of TIMESTAMP, which allows for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as a default. (More recent releases support a similar type of default for DATETIME as well.) But for a VARCHAR column, default is either `NULL` or a literal.

---

To get a value automatically assigned to the column, you could use MySQL BEFORE INSERT trigger (and a BEFORE UPDATE trigger)

Something like this perhaps:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER mytable_bi 
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.ip_a = INET_NTOA(NEW.ip_n);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

If you want to keep the values "in sync", you'd want a corresponding BEFORE UPDATE trigger, in the event that the value of `ip_n` is changed by an UPDATE statement.

Comment: objective is to get the value calculated from ip_n column based on internal function. how to do that then?

Comment: With MySQL, you could create BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers that assign a value to the column. Or, use a database *other* than MySQL (e.g. MariaDB) supports virtual columns.